# Read response of soap webservice

Tags: web-services, soap

Hi everyone in my company we use a bpms so i can't use packages and so on, i want to call a soap webservice and use it's response but after convert response to string, in export just is "Searchresult" text.
what is searchresult?
How can I fetch Data of searchresult?
Tanks for your help.

`Myweb.service mb = new Myweb.service(); var txt= mb.mymethod('5').ToString(); print(txt);`